# Conversion of VS 2010 C++ project to VS 2008

Tags: c++, compilation, game-engine

A couple of days ago, id Software released the [source code of Doom 3 BFG edition](https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM-3-BFG/). It is a VS 2010 solution with C++ projects in it. I want to compile it. Since I don't have a lot of money to buy a new VS license every two years, I use VS 2008. A year ago, when D3 code (VS 2010 too) was released, someone made files for VS 2008 and they worked. I dont think that this guy is going to do the same thing for this release. So I guess, I have to do it myself. Is there a way to convert automatically VS 2010 C++ project files to VS 2008 projects, w/o having access to VS 2010?

Comment: Did you read? `We expect the solution file is compatible with the Express releases` so you can use the express version which is free.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you simply download the [free](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2010-express) Visual C++ 2010 Express?

Comment: I tried to compile it on Visual 2010 Express (on my 10 year old computer, it took a long time to install it), and it did not work. "atlbase.h" file is missing (it is available on professional versions only). Right now I'm downloading WDK, maybe I will find that file there.